# Where is MessagesController : ApiController in the SDK 4 bot framework template

Tags: botframework, asp.net-apicontroller

I am not able to find Api Controllers in my bot template that I downloaded fomr my Web app bot. Where should "public class MessagesController : ApiController" reside?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The programming model in V4 is new and doesn't use controllers. Instead you create a class that implements `IBot` which you then register using idiomatic .NET Core configuration APIs during startup. Specifically you call `services.AddBot<YourBot>(…)` in `ConfigureServices` and then `appBuilder.UseBotFramework()` in `Configure`.

You can [take a look at `Startup.cs`](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/00.empty-bot/Startup.cs) from [the "empty" bot in the samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/00.empty-bot) to see an example of this.

From there [I suggest reading the "How Bots Work" documentation for V4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-basics?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=cs) to get a good high level overview of the core concepts, such as turns and the turn context, in V4.